# GRPC protobuff compiler

Tags: grpc

Although I followed all the steps of the the GRPC documentation, when I try to compile my proto files  it doesn't work.

by the way when run the command protoc-gen-go, I get the message: command not found.

following it is my .bash_profile

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After trying to find a solution, I discovered that the lines on my .bash_profile, were on a incorrect sequence, following is my bash now:
[image]